# how to Load initial window controller from storyboard?

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, storyboard

I have gone through many questoions but none of them snaswers my query.
I am trying to load initial window programmatically
Here is what I have done.

I have added main.swift as-

```
import Cocoa

private func runApplication(
    application: NSApplication         = NSApplication.sharedApplication(),
    delegate: NSApplicationDelegate?   = AppDelegate(),
    bundle: NSBundle                   = NSBundle.mainBundle(),
    nibName: String                    = "MainMenu",
    var topLevelObjects: NSArray?      = nil) {
        setApplicationDelegate(application, delegate)
}

private func setApplicationDelegate(application: NSApplication, delegate: NSApplicationDelegate?) -> NSApplication {
    if let delegate = delegate {
        application.delegate = delegate
    }
    return application
}

runApplication()
```

Appdelegate.swift is-

```
import Cocoa

//@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var appControl:AppFlow?
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {

    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }
    override init() {
        //
        self.appControl = AppFlow()
        super.init()
    }



}
```

And in AppFlow I am trying to load window controller from storyboard.-

```
import Cocoa

class AppFlow{
    let initialStoryBoard:NSStoryboard?
    override init() {
        self.initialStoryBoard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main" , bundle : nil)
        super.init()
        var windowController = (self.initialStoryBoard?.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("mainWindow")) as! NSWindowController
        windowController.window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)     
    }

}
```

But I am not able to launch initial window controller and view controller. App starts and terminates automatically, no window is presented to user.

What I am doing wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: did you have any success with your approach?

Answer (score 6):

Here is what I did in order to load initial window from storyboard (as well as `MainMenu`) programmatically without attribute `@NSApplicationMain` and function `NSApplicationMain(_, _)`

File: **AppConfig.swift** (Swift 4)

```
struct AppConfig {

   static var applicationClass: NSApplication.Type {
      guard let principalClassName = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["NSPrincipalClass"] as? String else {
         fatalError("Seems like `NSPrincipalClass` is missed in `Info.plist` file.")
      }
      guard let principalClass = NSClassFromString(principalClassName) as? NSApplication.Type else {
         fatalError("Unable to create `NSApplication` class for `\(principalClassName)`")
      }
      return principalClass
   }

   static var mainStoryboard: NSStoryboard {
      guard let mainStoryboardName = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["NSMainStoryboardFile"] as? String else {
         fatalError("Seems like `NSMainStoryboardFile` is missed in `Info.plist` file.")
      }

      let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: NSStoryboard.Name(mainStoryboardName), bundle: Bundle.main)
      return storyboard
   }

   static var mainMenu: NSNib {
      guard let nib = NSNib(nibNamed: NSNib.Name("MainMenu"), bundle: Bundle.main) else {
         fatalError("Resource `MainMenu.xib` is not found in the bundle `\(Bundle.main.bundlePath)`")
      }
      return nib
   }

   static var mainWindowController: NSWindowController {
      guard let wc = mainStoryboard.instantiateInitialController() as? NSWindowController else {
         fatalError("Initial controller is not `NSWindowController` in storyboard `\(mainStoryboard)`")
      }
      return wc
   }
}
```

File **main.swift** (Swift 4)

```
// Making NSApplication instance from `NSPrincipalClass` defined in `Info.plist`
let app = AppConfig.applicationClass.shared

// Configuring application as a regular (appearing in Dock and possibly having UI)
app.setActivationPolicy(.regular)

// Loading application menu from `MainMenu.xib` file.
// This will also assign property `NSApplication.mainMenu`.
AppConfig.mainMenu.instantiate(withOwner: app, topLevelObjects: nil)

// Loading initial window controller from `NSMainStoryboardFile` defined in `Info.plist`.
// Initial window accessible via property NSWindowController.window
let windowController = AppConfig.mainWindowController
windowController.window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)

app.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
app.run()
```

Note regarding `MainMenu.xib` file:

Xcode application template creates storyboard with `Application Scene` which contains `Main Menu`. At the moment seems there is no way programmatically load `Main Menu` from `Application Scene`. But there is Xcode file template `Main Menu`, which creates `MainMenu.xib` file, which we can load programmatically.

Comment: I am trying to get this to work with Swift 5. It seems to work ok except for loading the main menu. 

 "could not load the nibName: MainMenu in bundle NSBundle"

Comment: Never mind...I finally came to fully understand your note on the Main Menu. I figured out that I needed to first create a file from File->New->File and select "Main Menu".

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you start (and maintain) an application's main run loop. See `@NSApplicationMain`. This causes the main run loop to be set up and run until it's terminated. There's no need for a `main.swift` file any longer, as you can just put this into your app delegate's file directly.

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!


    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
    }

}
```

Xcode's new application project template does this for you.

Comment: Thanks for help. I was just trying to do all those things myself to understand how this template works. I have intentionally commented @NSApplicationMain.