# Can you do test setup before application loads in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, unit-testing

I am a Swift/MacOS newbie working on a MacOS application does some setup involving keychain access and API calls in the viewDidLoad() methods in the main ViewController.

I am working on unit tests for my models, so I don't need and in fact do not want the code in viewDidLoad() to run. However, from what I can tell, the app gets loaded and those methods run before the test case setup() method, so I don't know how I could do any mocking or other actions.

I am using Xcode 11.5 and Swift 5.

Comment: Well the obvious answer to me is to not do any API calls from a view controller but instead from a specific service class that you call from the view controller. If you on top of that use dependency injection in your view controller it will be much easier to mock the service class and test the view controller.

Comment: Unit tests will launch the code that you have set as the ‘NSApplicationMain’ so it will setup the window and view controller automatically. You could add code to setup that manually instead of using the annotation, then you’d use a different NSApplicationMain class as the entry point.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson the API calls are already in a service class, but the view controller loads before the testcase setup, so I don't understand where I have a chance to inject a dependency. I am not (in this case) testing the view controller, it just gets autoloaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it would be to have an separate `NSApplicationMain` for when unit tests are run vs one for "normal" runs.

First remove the `@NSApplicationMain` annotation from your current `AppDelegate` class. It should end up looking something like this:

**AppDelegate.swift**

```swift
import AppKit

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
  func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    print("Debug/Production run")

    // Insert code here to initialize your application
  }

  func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
  }
}
```

Now create a new file called `AppDelegateUnitTesting.swift` and it's source should look like this:

**AppDelegateUnitTesting.swift**

```swift
import Foundation
import Cocoa

class AppDelegateTesting: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
  func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    print("Unit Testing Run")
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
  }

  func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
  }
}
```

Now add a new file called `main.swift` this file will determine in which environment our app is running, the source should be something like this:

**main.swift**

```swift
import Foundation
import Cocoa

let isRunningTests = NSClassFromString("XCTestCase") != nil &&
  ProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments.contains("-XCUnitTests")

fileprivate var delegate: NSApplicationDelegate?

if !isRunningTests {
  delegate = AppDelegate()
  NSApplication.shared.delegate = delegate

  // See this Answer to initialize the Windows programmatically
  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/44604229/496351
} else {
  delegate = AppDelegateTesting()
  NSApplication.shared.delegate = delegate

}
NSApplication.shared.run()
```

To determine whether it's running in a Unit Test environment it checks if it can load the `XCTestClass` (which is only injected when testing) and it checks for the presence of the `-XCUnitTest` command line argument, we have to set this argument ourselves as part of the Scheme's `Test` action as shown in the image below

[image: Test Args]

After doing all of this, you should see the message `"Debug/Production run"` printed when you press the play button and you should see the message `"Unit Testing Run"` printed whenever you run your unit tests.

You'll most likely have to add code to load the initial window programmatically this other answer shows how to do it:

- [how to Load initial window controller from storyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44604229/496351)